# c# get all the opened windows title

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer

I am writing a program to get all the windows title of Internet Explorer. Suppose if 2 windows of Internet Explorer are opened, the my program should show the titles & get the handles of all the Internet Explorer windows. Here is my program

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
    }
}
```

This program is working but only gets a single window's text. When I see, there are 3 to 4 `iexplore.exe` were running when 2 to 3 Internet Explorer windows are opened. While looking other answers, all they are using with one process, but there are 3-4 `iexplore.exe` present. How can I get all the handles of opened Internet Explorer windows ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ManagmenObjectSearcher` to get all the parents object from a certain process

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                if (process.Id == 4160)//this is chrome id for example/
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                    List<Process> a = GetChild(process);

                    foreach( Process p in a)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, process.MainWindowTitle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public  static List<Process> GetChild(Process process)
    {
        List<Process> children = new List<Process>();
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format("Select * From Win32_Process Where ParentProcessID={0}", process.Id));

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
        {
            children.Add(Process.GetProcessById(Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessID"])));
        }

        return children;
    }
```

Goodluck.

Comment: For iexplore.exe, it Is not working as the iexplore.exe's process ID becomes which window of internet explorer is open. You could also check this.